# Moving multiple files to multiple directories based on filename pattern, while excluding some

Tags: linux, loops, wildcard, move

As a Linux noob (that wants to learn!), I have been browsing and searching but unfortunately not been able to come up with the right solution for my problem. I've got a directory containing several files (a lot) that I'd would like to move to different directories (to be made also). To be more specific:

my directory is: /data/myowndir/ and the files each have names such as

> - CV02_T1_[random characters].REC
> - PM03_T2_[random characters].PAR

I would like to move each file to a subdirectory inside this directory by their respective first 7 characters (of the filename), such that:

> - CV02_T1_*.REC ---> /data/myowndir/CV02_T1
> - CV02_T1_*.PAR ---> /data/myowndir/CV02_T1 (same directory as previous)
> - PM03_T1_*.REC ---> /data/myowndir/PM03_T1
> - PV05_T2_*.PAR ---> /data/myowndir/PV05_T2
> - etc.

So I want to move multiple files **and** create these multiple directories.

However, there are two contraints.

1. The directory also contains files with the extension .nii , which **I don't want to move**.
2. Second, some files have **filenames** containing the string *sT13*, which I would like to move to a separate directory, such that:

> PM03_T2_[random characters]sT13[random characters].PAR ---> /data/myowndir/PM03_struc

(so only the first 5 characters of the filename and the additional string [struc] added to the new directoryname)

Anyone know how to do this? Should I write a script or can I do this from the command terminal? I've been reading other answers to similar questions and man pages for mv, mmv, find, while, for, rsync; but I don't know how to put it together.

---

EDIT:
If my question is **too specific** as implied, then let me rephraze it first to make it more clear and drop the contraints:

How do I move multiple files from a directory into multiple subdirectories, based on the first part of their filenames?

Comment: Too localized.  This is unlikely to be of any help to future visitors.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean by "too localized". Please note, English is not my native language.

Comment: It implied that the question, as is, appears to be very very *specific* and the solution isn't likely to help any future visitors.

Comment: I see. I will wait to see if someone will be kind enough to help me with it regardless. Even if I get downvoted a lot. However, I will edit my question to improve this 'localization problem' for future visitor purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that there are more that two 7-letter sequences at the beginning of your filenames (because otherwise you could just mv commands with bash extension). On bash, fist move the 'special' files with the letter sequence in the middle to the new directory:

```
cd  /data/myowndir/
for filename in *sT13*.*; do
   if [ "${filename: -4}" != ".nii" ]; then
      dir_name=${filename:0:5};
      mkdir -p ${dir_name}struc
      mv -i $filename ${dir_name}struc/${filename}
   fi
done
```

then move all the other files to their respective new folders:

```
for filename in *.*; do
   if [ "${filename: -4}" != ".nii" ]; then
      dir_name=${filename:0:7};
      mkdir -p $dir_name
      mv -i $filename $dir_name/${filename}
   fi
done
```

the `-p` option for the `mkdir` command assures that you don't get errors if the directory already exists. `${string:0:7}` selects the first 7 letters of a string

Comment: yes, each file has different first 7 character sequence, including the *ST13* ones. Your first line creates one directory and places all of my files inside this directory, however, eacht *sT13* file should be in its own directory.

Comment: I noticed already and edited the answer -- does this suit your needs?

Comment: it says:

> dirname: extra operand 'CM01_'
> Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
> mv: missing destination file operand after 'CM01_T1_WIP_sT13DTFE_.PAR'

Comment: what shell are you in?

Comment: I just went to 'terminal emulator' and typed 'bash', that's not the way to go?

Comment: my bad. Try `dir_name` instead of `dirname` and make sure that there are no whitespaces before or after the equality (=) sign.

Comment: I tried it and it created all directories, but it renamed all my files with the sting sT13 to their first 5 characters, and didn't move them.

also, it combined the two files that had same names but different extensions into one file..

Comment: Oh dear, that's because I copied and pasted the second part to solve the first part and made a mistake while editing. I did another edit, now it should work. Also, the `mv` command does not combine files. It most likely renamed the first file and then replaced it with the second (giving it the same name). I edit the answer above such that this cannot happen in the future (by adding the '-i' option (which imo should be the default for all unexperienced users))

Comment: Thanx a lot, it worked!! However, I did not need the 

/${filename} at the end of the mv command?

Comment: No problem. The /${filename} was a final 'security measure' :)